# Getting Offset of keyword found in a field in ElasticSearch v7.3

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elastisearch v7.3 and I am trying to get the results and hits of the keywords that is being queried for a particular field.

I am seeing that in Elasticsearch there is highlight query that is getting the required field but, that too in italicized or emphasized way. I want to get the word offset that it found on the particular field from which I can know at which position in the field is the value present.

Is there any way to return the word offset of the keyword found in that field?
Please help....Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it all in single request. You can use `_mtermvectors` for such operation.

Example:

1) Add document

```
POST twitter/_doc/
{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch"
}
```

2) Find start and end offsets of every word in field "message" ("trying", "out" and "elasticsearch")

```
POST /_mtermvectors
{
   "docs": [
      {
         "_index": "twitter",
         "_id": "othBtW0Bf0bJZDNlKhIA",
         "offsets": true,
         "field_statistics" : false,
         "fields" : [ "message"]
      }
   ]
}

"term_vectors" : {
        "message" : {
          "terms" : {
            "elasticsearch" : {
              "term_freq" : 1,
              "tokens" : [
                {
                  "position" : 2,
                  "start_offset" : 11,
                  "end_offset" : 24
                }
              ]
            },
            "out" : {
              "term_freq" : 1,
              "tokens" : [
                {
                  "position" : 1,
                  "start_offset" : 7,
                  "end_offset" : 10
                }
              ]
            },
            "trying" : {
              "term_freq" : 1,
              "tokens" : [
                {
                  "position" : 0,
                  "start_offset" : 0,
                  "end_offset" : 6
                }
              ]
            }
          }
```

Hope you get the idea

Comment: Hi @DejanMaric, I have got the idea but don't you think that this is a very tedious task to do? I would have thousands of document and with that, I can look the keyword in multiple fields also and if I set the offset manually then it will take a lot of efforts.